# Packet dropped even when firewall is turned off in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

We have a windows 2008 server and lately we have started seeing a lot of 5152 Events logged in the server (*Windows Filtering Platform blocked a packet*).

We have an inbound rule configured to allow connections to the port which was working fine earlier. I'm not sure what changed lately. But this doesn't make any sense.

The packet is dropped even when windows firewall is disabled. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the packet actually dropped, or is it incorrectly logged as dropped? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969257 If it's really being dropped, what Shane said.

Comment: I believe I have encountered a similar issue, did you get any resolution on this? My question is - http://serverfault.com/questions/688687/windows-filtering-platform-dropping-sql-server-connections

Answer (score 1):

Filtering platform can be used by more than just windows firewall; I'd check if your host security (antivirus) software has a firewall feature enabled.